# Energy calculation for a short circuit of a battery

Tags: power, batteries, temperature, short-circuit, time

I have a battery cell with the given datasheet: [WB-LYP100AHA](http://www.nothnagel-marine.de/media/downloads/Lithium_Akkus/Manual%20WB-LYP100AHA%20Winston-Lithium-ion%20Batterie.pdf?XTCsid=d902de6098dfe7df8add8609624d2cb0)

So I can calculate the short circuit current with the internal resistance as:

$$ \frac{3.5V}{0.00045Ohm} = 7777.78A $$

So the internal power generated is:

$$7777.78A^2*0.00045Ohm = 27222.23W$$

Energy it takes to heat up a cell by 35 kelvin. Cell weight: $3.3kg$

With a heat capacity of \$4 \frac {kJ}{kg * K}\$ I get:
$$4000 \frac{Ws}{kg*K} * 3.3kg * 35K = 462000Ws$$

Time it takes the cell to heat up by \$35\$ kelvin:
$$ \frac{462000Ws}{27222.23W} = 16.97sec$$

Are these steps ok for a rough calculation or is there a mistake / better way?

Comment: I know next to nothing about this kind of battery, but I would expect the internal resistance to rise very rapidly if the discharge current exceeds the specified continuous current of 3CA (?= 300A).  Your 7.7kA is higher even than the specified impulse current of 10CA (?= 1000A).  So I wouldn't expect to try your experiment more than once.

Comment: 450uohm might be the 'small current' resistance, say up to 3C, I doubt the same figure holds for short circuit current, and I doubt the same figure holds beyond a moment's operation, polarisation will increase it, and change of temperature might alter in either direction.  But assuming you haven't made any arithmetic errors, then given your stated assumptions, that looks reasonable.

Comment: The problem is that internal resistance is going to change very fast. You might get transient peak power of 27KW but that won't last very long. Are you trying to calculate total work done by a short circuit? Until the battery is completely dead? This calculation is very hard to model. Batteries are strange creatures

Comment: When you short it, whatever you short it with, will have a resistance of its own and a contact resistance, both which play a role too in this case.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That is for sure. I just want to make a rough worst case calculation. If there is a better way to calulate it please give it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the datasheet, the operating discharge current is given by the opertaing discharge voltage and internal resistance which is: $$I_d=V_d/R_i$$
From the datasheet your discharge voltage is 2.8V @25°C and the internal resistance is 0,45 mOhm which gives you a discharge current of 6223 A.
But, the maximum discharge voltage is when the battery is charged at 100% if your battery is fully charged at 3.5V, then your calculations are good.   Note that a 3CA means that the discharge current will discharge the entire battery at the rate of 300A in 1 hour.

Comment: *the internal resistance is 0,45 mOhm which gives you a discharge current of 6223 A* That's only true if you could guarantee that the internal resistance **really** is 0.45 mohm at I = 6223 A. Which no-one on this planet will guarantee you. You're all assuming batteries to behave in an "ideal" way and they don't. The chemical processes inside the battery have their limitations.

Comment: Of course you take 0,45 mOhm! You have to secure the battery by limit the current, you'll take max internal resistance which is 0,45 mOhm. Assuming that you take less than 0,45 mOhm and you don't have any data to confirm the value your current will exceed the max value and you'll damage the battery. 6223 A is the secure current for the battery in case of short circuit of the battery. The internal resistance can be less but not more than 0,45 mOhm

Comment: *you don't have any data to confirm the value your current will exceed the max value* No I don't but the manufacturer does not state a max current just for fun. If the battery could safely deliver 7x more current then I am quite sure they would put that in the datasheet because that would be a selling point.

Comment: *The internal resistance can be less but not more than 0,45 mOhm* Where did you get this wisdom ? From the datasheet perhaps ? The same datasheet where the maximum current is listed as 10C ? Which is 1000 A which is 6.223 times more than the current at which you think that internal resistance is still valid ?

Comment: The max Impulse discharge current is different from the short circuit current.

Comment: You're still assuming that the short circuit current is only limited by the internal resistance. It is not. The chemical processes inside the battery have certain limitations. These come into play when discharging the battery with more current than the maximum ratings from the datasheet. The pulsed discharge current is higher than the continuous discharge current because a pulsed current allows the battery to "recover" after the pulse. There is no guarantee what will happen if you short the battery but the current will be less than 6223A for sure.

Comment: In case of short circuit you can damage the battery for sure.  Your battery will vent if ou exceed a defined time and maybe explode. But saying that the maximum current of the battery in case of short circuit is a 10 AC is not true, the short circuit current can be 10 times more than the max impulse discharge current.

Comment: Short circuit a battery is not a safe, i'bet you can short circuit your battery for few seconds and the current will be more than 10 CA i'lm sure!

Comment: Take a look in this example, Schneider calculate the short circuit current based on the internal resistance:  http://www2.schneider-electric.com/documents/electrical-distribution/en/shared/interactive-catalogue/lvped2080006en/pdfs/page_019.pdf

Comment: *But saying that the maximum current of the battery in case of short circuit is a 10 AC* Where did I state that ?? Nowhere ! What I state is that you should not exceed that 10 C Ampere (not 10A C) because that is the maximum current stated in the datasheet. That does not mean that a higher current will not flow. It means that the user should not let more  current flow. Meaning :do not short circuit the battery.

Comment: And again you're comparing the **theoretical** (Schneider) with the practical (the WB-LYP100AHA datasheet). Schneider's stuff is all **theory**. There is no mention of an actual battery having a certain maximum discharge current. Theoretic calculations disregard many things to make a point and show how the calculation is done, **in theory**. Practice is more complicated, you cannot simply apply a theoretical exercise to a practical situation. OP made mistake of referring to the datasheet of the  WB-LYP100AHA instead of keeping this a purely theoretical exercise.

Comment: Ok, i understand! You can use this calculation of short circuit current to size a fuse for your battery for safety application i did it before. some times a fuse has to withstand a few thousands of current and cut the battery power only n case of the short circuit for more than 30s for example.

Answer (score -1):

I would treat that "internal resistance" more as a dV/dI value, meaning, when you draw 1 Amp more current, the voltage will drop 0.00045 Volts.

The current range for which this is valid has to be within the "reasonable values", I would use the maximum current mentioned in the datasheet so for this battery, less than 3C Ampere which is 300 A for this battery.

Your 7778 A is purely theoretical as it will very likely damage the battery.

The maximum **impulse** discharge current is 10C A so 1000 A, your 7778 A is exceeding that by more than a factor 7. This means:

The data in the datasheet is no longer valid.
The battery will be damaged, it will probably explode.

Your calculation is a purely theoretical one and does not apply to this battery. If you want a valid number for this battery then do not exceed the max. conditions as specified in the datasheet !

Comment: My calculation shall be a theoretical one. In the end I want to see what happens if you short out the batterie (How long it takes to get to the thermal runaway).

Comment: OK, but **why** then link this **theoretical** calculation to this **practical** battery ? Due to the practical limitations of the battery, the calculation is pointless. If you want to keep the calculation then throw out the battery and say that you're using a hypothetical battery of 4V, 100 Ah and Rs = 0.45 mohm.

Comment: I took the batterie to get some basic values for the calculation.